# how to gracefully close task loops in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, task, python-asyncio

I'm currently creating a discord bot that contains two task loops called `check_members` and `check_music`.
When a user enters the `offline` command, I'd like to gracefully stop these loops. I wrote this piece of code in my Cog class:

```py
class MusicBot(commands.Cog):
    # function called when bot is closing.
    See [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cog_unload#discord.ext.commands.Cog.cog_unload)
    def cog_unload(self):
        print("Debug")
        self.check_members.cancel()
        self.check_music.cancel()
        print(self.check_members.is_running())
        print(self.check_music.is_running())

    # example of a task loop I have:
    @tasks.loop(seconds=5)
    async def check_members(self):
        [code...]
```

In another script, I call the bot.close() function as follows:

```py
await ctx.send("Going offline! See ya later.")
if self.voice is not None:
await self.disconnect()
await self.bot.close()
sys.exit(0)
```

When a user calls the `offline` command, that's what the bot prints out:

```py
Debug
True
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='discord.py: on_message' coro=<Client._run_event() done, defined at /home/liuk23/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py:401> exception=SystemExit(0)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/liuk23/Desktop/coding/Discord-bot-3/main.py", line 67, in <module>
    loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 600, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1896, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/home/liuk23/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/liuk23/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1392, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "/home/liuk23/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1389, in process_commands
    await self.invoke(ctx)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/liuk23/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1347, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/liuk23/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 986, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/liuk23/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 190, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/liuk23/Desktop/coding/Discord-bot-3/music.py", line 223, in offline
    await self.functions.offline(ctx)
  File "/home/liuk23/Desktop/coding/Discord-bot-3/funcitons.py", line 241, in offline
    sys.exit(0)
SystemExit: 0
```

As you can notice, the `Debug` text gets printed out, so the `cog_unload` function get successfully called.
Although I am closing the loops, I get the `Task was never retrieved` error. Am I misunderstanding the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys%20exit#sys.exit) documentation:

> Raise a SystemExit exception, signaling an intention to exit the interpreter.

What is happening is that the `offline` task, by throwing `SystemExit`, stops, but since no other task is awaiting on it, that exception is never retrieved.

The underlying problem is that, to quit the application, rather than throwing through `sys.exit`, it would be better to stop the running loop cleanly. For example, if the loop was run with `loop.run_until_complete(some_future)`, it's necessary to set that future with `some_future.set_result(some_result)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I eventually fixed my problem in another way that I will explain for people having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by stopping the main loop that holds all the bot.
In my main script I instantiate the bot in the following manner:

```py
    try:
        # loop runs until stop is called
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    # finally block is called when loop is being stopped
    finally:
        # stop and close loop
        loop.stop()
        sys.exit(0)
```

By calling `loop.stop()` in another script, the finally block in `main.py` will be called and will successfully close the loop and the whole script.
Thanks to @Ulisse Bordignon for your answer